# work around for triggers that update the same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, generated

I am building a nba_players table in MySQL. It has a column for players height in inches (pl_ht_inches). It also has a column (pl_ht_feet) where it lists a players height in feet. For example nba_player Michael Jordan has pl_ht_feet = '6-6' and the pl_ht_inches is updated using the following statement:

`update nba_players ab
        inner join
    feet_hieght_tb bc on ab.pl_ht_feet = bc.hieght
set
    ab.pl_ht_inches = bc.total_inches`

this statement updates nba_players.pl_ht_inches using table 'feet_hieght_tb' which has two columns

1. hieght - hieght varchar(4) with data like '6-6' which is imperial measurement
2. total_inches int(3) which lists height in inches. for example hieght '6-6' would be total_inches =  78.

I then used a trigger with the update statement. I subsequently found out that you cant reference the same table as the insert statement in the trigger for that table. The trigger reads as follows:

`delimiter $$
create trigger 
after_nba_players_insert

    after insert on nba_players 
    for each row 
begin 
    update nba_players ab

        inner join  feet_hieght_tb bc on ab.pl_ht_feet = bc.hieght 
    set  ab.pl_ht_inches = bc.total_inches; 
end$$
delimiter ;`

this produces error 1442 when I attempt to insert new data into nba_players which means the trigger is updating the same table as as the insert into the nba_players table.

So then I tried to trigger the update by creating a stored procedure where I included the same update statement that i used for the trigger. I can call the procedure manually after doing an insert into nba_players and it works fine. But if I use the stored procedure in the trigger I get error 1442.

I dont want to have to remember to call the procedure every time I do an insert into nba_players and would like to automate this task if I could.

Is there an alternative to using triggers or stored procedure to update a column using data from a different table.

I have been researching generated columns but they dont allow select statements. What I mean by this is that the nba_players.pl_ht_inches is a foreign key to the table feet_hieght_tb that references total_inches where nba_players.pl_ht_feet = feet_hieght_tb.height. I would rather the foreign key update on its own rather than having to do this manually.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: feet-inches -> inches, even to a metric snob like me, is just maths - you shouldn't need a lookup table (or slide rule) to do this. The right bit of [string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html), [CAST xx AS UNSIGNED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html), one multiply, on add, will get you a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Comment: You *can* manipulate the *current row* in a trigger, just not other rows. You do not need an `update` for this, just a `set new.pl_ht_inches = (select ...)`. Please see any [example in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Apart from that, you can a) use a generated column or do a direct calculation in the trigger (or in the select), as the definition for how many inches `6-6` are rarely changes, or b) keep `6-6` in your table, and do a join to the lookup table when you need the value. Currently, you are duplicating information/denormalizing your data.